# Scrollview becomes laggy after scrolling too far

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my app, I have a basic wall with user generated content. Just like facebook, 9gag, instagram, etc have one. I am basically filling my scrollview with new content every time the bottom is reached:

```
 scrlview.ScrollReachedBottom += delegate
            {                 
                    List<KumulosHelper.Objects.Picture> pictures = KumulosHelper.Pictures.getNewestXPhotosFromUserInRange(strUsername, "2", startNumberOfTask.ToString(), "0");
                    foreach (var picture in pictures)
                    {
                        startNumberOfTask++;
                        addPictureInfo(picture);
                    }
                    if (pictures.Count < 2)
                    {
                        stopLoading = true;
                    }
        };
```

There are two problems:

1. The Scrollview hangs until the content has loaded. I noticed that in other apps such as the above ones, the scrollview starts scrolling and the content fills in as soon as it has loaded.
2. After scrolling down for a while, the scrollview becomes laggy. It usually scrolls with somewhat 60 frames. In a certain spot (that is always the same) it drops to something like 10 frames. Scroll back up and everything is back to normal.

I think both issues could be solved using another component. Maybe a recycler view? What would I need to adjust to get from the scrollview to another component?

Comment: `RecyclerView` will save your time.

Comment: `RecycleView` and `ViewHolder` will help you get risk of `ScrollView` issue